# Matching two columns from one sheet to the next then sum the third

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I've searched everywhere for an answer but haven't been able to find my same problem.

I have a Google Sheet containing two sheets.

Sheet #1:

| Site | hour | number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| site1 | 0 | 333 |
| site1 | 1 | 123 |
| site2 | 0 | 253 |
| site3 | 1 | 124 |

Sheet #2:

| Site | hour | number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| site1 | 0 | 100 |
| site1 | 1 | 124 |
| site1 | 2 | 363 |
| site1 | 3 | 568 |
| site1 | 4 | 876 |

I would like to match the `site` and `hour` from Sheet 1 in Sheet 2, and sum the numbers in the third column.

In this example `site1` would equal `224`, I hope that makes sense.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: Can the hours be repeated (duplicated) for a site in sheet #2, or all they all unique?

Comment: Hours would be hours of the day. 0-23.

Comment: Sheet 1 contains todays data, so it might only have particial data.

For example 0-5 but sheet two will have hours 0-23.

I would like to match the hours in sheet one to sheet two, this will give me the number for the previous day during the same period

Answer (score 0):

Try using vlookup with the first two columns in the two sheets joined together:

```
=ArrayFormula(query({A2:A,vlookup(A2:A&"|"&B2:B,{Sheet2!A2:A&"|"&B2:B,Sheet2!C2:C},2,false)},
"select Col1,sum(Col2) where Col1 is not null group by Col1"))
```

[image]